# Angular - Display different dropdown values based on condition

Tags: html, angular, dropdown, angular-ng-if

I am displaying `data` value as dropdown if below condition in html is met.

I would like to add another condition where on `change of another dropdown which contains companies name I show` data1`value. For example if 1st dropdown (companies name) is changed to`Amazon`then I only display`data1` as its value

```
  <dd>
              <mat-select *ngIf="editMode"; else showData" [disabled]="!editMode" 
                          [(ngModel)]="term.data" (ngModelChange)="recordModified.emit()">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let tag of data" [value]="tag.value">{{tag.text}}</mat-option>
              </mat-select>
              <ng-template #showData>{{term.data}}</ng-template>
            </dd>
```

```
  data = [
    {value: '1', text: 'Amazon'},
    {value: '2', text: 'Google'},
    {value: '3', text: 'Apple'},
```

```
  data1 = [
    {value: '1', text: 'Amazon'},
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather you want to access the data that has been selected by the dropdown, correct? You're close... check out this demo for a working version https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xmxqpg?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts